# Node.js mssql module is very slow

Tags: javascript, sql-server, node.js

I am trying to improve the performance of a Node.js REST API that uses SQL Server as its database. This API can be very slow (e.g. 1.5s response time).

After digging into the code, I have found that the JavaScript code itself is quite fast (runs for less than 1ms) but what is slowing everything down is the sql queries executed via the mssql module.

Even queries as simple as `"SELECT [id] from [users]"` take around 1 to 2 seconds to complete when the 'users' table only contains 5 rows! This issue seems to be happening within the mssql module because when I run the same queries on SSMS or via python (pymssql), they complete almost instantly as they should.

Does anyone know of a solution for this or an alternative module that could be used? (any other suggestions are welcome)

This is the code I use to make the queries:

```
const config = {...}

var sql = require('mssql');
var date;

sql.connect(config)
.then(pool => {
    date = Date.now();
    return pool.request()
    .query('select [id] from [users]');
})
.then(result => {
    console.dir('This query took ' + (Date.now() - date) + 'ms to return ' + result.recordset.length + ' rows!');
})
.catch(err => {
   console.log(err);
})

sql.on('error', err => {
    console.log(err);
})
```

and the output is:

```
'This query took 1287ms to return 5 rows!'
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Found the solution! The config object can have a pool.min property that specifies the minimum number of connections that must remain active.

I did not know about this property and had thought that the module kept the connection active by default, now I added pool.min = 5 and everything works much better, problem solved!

Hopefully this can help some people

Comment: I tried using the same solution but it didn't work. Why would setting the minimum pool size to 5 improve speed?

Comment: I think if there isn't a minimum number of active connexions, the module has to connect and disconnect for every query and this is what would be taking so much time. This is only what seems logical to me but I could be wrong since I don't really know the module that well.

Comment: Setting pool.min = 5 and using a global pool variable works for me! I think default value pool.min = 0 and re-initializing pool variable every time was actually not leveraging the pool of connections and was resetting it every-time.